# Visual Studio - C++ executable looks for mangled names

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a .dll with non-mangled names (verified with depends.exe), but the application I'm building with VS looks for a mangled name.  In this case, the DLL is called libEGL.dll and exports many functions, such as:

- eglCreateImageKHR
- eglChooseConfig
- eglCreateContext

However, when I use 'Dependency Walker' to view the .exe which links to libEGL.dll, it's looking for these functions:

- **_eglCreateImageKHR@20**
- eglChooseConfig
- eglCreateContext

Now, I'm having a very tough time trying to figure out why it's looking for `_eglCreateImageKHR@20` instead of `eglCreateImageKHR`.  In the header file which declares it, `eglext.h`, the declaration for this function is surrounded by `extern "C" {` tags.

Does anyone know why the executable is trying to find the 'mangled' name?

Comment: That's not a mangled name, it is a *decorated* name that indicates that the calling convention for the function is __stdcall.   The linker is supposed to use the actual exported name, as directed by the DLL's import library.  Pretty unclear what might be wrong with it.

Comment: double check all your source files. Probably some of them do not use proper `extern "C" {` approach.

Comment: Add a conflicting declaration (e.g. `extern "C" int eglCreateImageKHR(float);`) of the offending function in one of your translation units before including anything to trigger an error at the exact place where the function is declared. Also watch out for possible `#defines` messing with the function names. In any case, the detail to explain is why only one of several functions is treated like that.

Comment: Where did you get the `libEGL.dll` and the corresponding `libEGL.lib` you linked with?